# onTouchEvent in dialog

Tags: android, timer, touch-event, ontouchlistener, android-dialog

I have implemented button's `onLongClickListener` in Android `Dialog` which auto-decreases number using timers. Here is the code

```
myIncreaseTimer = new Timer();
final Runnable runnable_decrease = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        int txt = Integer.parseInt(length.getText().toString());
        txt -= 1;
        length.setText(String.valueOf(txt));
        if (txt == 0) {
            myIncreaseTimer.cancel();
            myIncreaseTimer.purge();
            myIncreaseTimer = new Timer();
        }
    }
};
btnMinus.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        myIncreaseTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(runnable_decrease);
            }
        }, 0, 300);
        return true;
    }
});
```

When I am inside of activity, not dialog, I can stop the decrease via `onTouchEvent` when a user touches the screen

```
@Override 
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        myIncreaseTimer.cancel();
        myIncreaseTimer.purge();
        myIncreaseTimer = new Timer();
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, I cannot do this in the dialog. Even more, the dialog does not have onTouchEvent.

Does anyone know how can I either implement `onTouchEvent` in `Dialog` or where should I stop the increase timer in the `Dialog`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't handle onTouch on Dialog so

**Create a Activity, implement onTouchListener on it,
and in manifest file**

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

So, now your activity is look like a DialogBox,

Comment: But make sure you extend  Activity, not AppcompctActivity and one more think which i want add here . If we set syle android:style/Theme.Dialog . activity title will shown . If you want to remove it use android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar

Answer (score 2):

because Dialog is not designed to handle raw onTouchEvents. consider creating an activity that would look like a dialog (transparent theme, no title bar) and override it's onTouchEvent method.